# Merge multiple linestring features into a single multilinestring

Tags: qgis, geojson, features, ogr2ogr, linestring

Using QGis or ogr2ogr how do I convert a vector file containing multiple linestrings features into a single multilinestring feature?

At the moment I've been doing this manually by converting the data to GeoJson and editing it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **Dissolve** tool from QGIS:

*Vector* > *Geoprocessing Tools* > *Dissolve*

[image: Dissolve toolbar]

[image: Dissolve interface]

Comment: Just what I needed. Never would have guess Dissolve was it. Thanks!