# Extract from a linestring layer, groups of linestrings to a multilinestring objects layer

Tags: qgis, linestring, qgis-processing, autocad-map

I've got a linestring layer with thousands of linestrings. I want to extract groups of linestrings to individual multilinestring objects.

In the following picture you can see a part of the layer with a lot of linestrings. Each object inside the red circles are composed of many single linestrings (different records in the layer). I want to obtain a layer with one unique multilinestring record for each object in the red circle.

[image]

I assume that i will have to control+select the linestrings that compose one object and do something to convert it to a multinestring record and add it to the new multilinestring layer but I can't see how to do this in QGIS.

I am open to using different software if there is not a solution to this in QGIS. I also use AutoCAD Map.

Comment: You can use the dissolf function of QGIS like it is explained in the answer to this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107883/merge-multiple-linestring-features-into-a-single-multilinestring